# mkdir with "/foldername" creates folder above root in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I've changed root directory of XAMPP to

```
S:\server\
```

instead of default htdocs folder.

now php operations that involve directories (like mkdir, rename, etc)
when i have "/" to create folder in root, it creates above it:

```
mkdir("/uploads/test", 0777, true);
```

makes

```
S:\uploads\test\
```

instead of

```
S:\server\uploads\test
```

how can i fix this? clearly those functions didnt create folder above htdocs in the default setup. ive tried adding virtual host but it didnt help

Comment: Have you tried with `mkdir("uploads/test",0777,true);` ?

Comment: that actually worked. but isnt that relative to the directory php file is executed from? is it not?

Comment: when you add `/` it actually points to root in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with static folder and relative path issue.

try to use

```
mkdir("./uploads/test", 0777, true);
```

instead

```
mkdir("/uploads/test", 0777, true);
```